# Move bootstrap navigation scroll down effect in angular

Tags: angular

I'm implementing a bootstrap template in my angular web app, specifically [this one](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-creative) and if you open its [live preview](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative), you will see navigation bar scroll down effect.

That navigation bar logic is located right here: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/js/creative.js

Probably this one:

```
 // Collapse Navbar
  var navbarCollapse = function() {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
      $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-scrolled");
    } else {
      $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-scrolled");
    }
  };
  // Collapse now if page is not at top
  navbarCollapse();
  // Collapse the navbar when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(navbarCollapse);
```

[Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z5Ly.png)

I want to put that logic in my angular. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @mikegross's post, that's a complete solution.

`@HostListener('window:scroll', [])` gets activated when you scroll down/up and then you check for y coordinate's offset. Basically, that's what your javascript code does but its typescript representation.

```
// typescript
@ViewChild('navbar', { static: false }) navbar: ElementRef;

@HostListener('window:scroll', []) onWindowScroll() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
        this.navbar.nativeElement.classList.add('navbar-scrolled');
    } else {
        this.navbar.nativeElement.classList.remove('navbar-scrolled');
    }
}

// html
<nav ... #navbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of techiques:

1) listen for event onScrool (add this hostlistener in the methods part)

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', []) onWindowScroll() {
  // do some stuff here when the window is scrolled
}
```

2) check offset of window and act on it with a condition

```
window.pageYOffset
```

3) based on a condition add and remove class attributes

```
document.getElementById('').setAttribute('class', 'yourClass')
```

You can combine all those techniques together to fit your descirption.